# How do I format this equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

I want to write this equation in Latex.

[image]

Sorry, I don't know what's the specific name of this kind of equation. I know title is so general.

Comment: Have a look at the document [mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) -- cases

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This cannot be solved with the standard `cases` environment provided by `amsmath`, but you can use `array`:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{@{} l c c @{}}
p & \text{fuego}    & p_{R}>R_{T}, p_{G}>G_{T}, p_{B}>B_{T} \\
p & \text{no-fuego} & \text{resto}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
```

For `\text` you need `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works fine. Only another little question, in your sample code I try to put \label to reference this equation but doesn't work. Any solution ?

Comment: An unnumbered equation doesn't admit a label. Use `equation` if you want to number and label it.

Comment: ok, thanks another time. Now works like i want.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the items centered you could use the `cases` environment.

If you do need them centered then using `array` as per egreg's solution is the simplest in this case, but you could also:

2. Add some manual spacing with `\hspace`, or
3. Use a `\makebox` with a specified width that looks good, or
4. Use `\widthof` (requires the `calc` package) to obtain precise lengths for the `\makebox` macro:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\cases|:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
p \quad\text{fuego}    &p_{R}>R_{T}, p_{G}>G_{T}, p_{B}>B_{T} \\
p \quad\text{no-fuego} &\text{resto}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\verb|\cases| with \verb|\hspace|:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
p \quad\text{\hspace{0.5em}fuego}    &p_{R}>R_{T}, p_{G}>G_{T}, p_{B}>B_{T} \\
p \quad\text{no-fuego} &\hspace{5.0em}\text{resto}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\verb|\cases| with \verb|\makebox|:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
p \quad\makebox[1.3cm][c]{fuego}    &\makebox[4.4cm][c]{$p_{R}>R_{T}, p_{G}>G_{T}, p_{B}>B_{T}$} \\
p \quad\makebox[1.3cm][c]{no-fuego} &\makebox[4.4cm][c]{resto}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\verb|\cases| with \verb|\makebox| with measured amounts:
\newcommand{\WidestColumnA}{no-fuego}
\newcommand{\WidestColumnB}{$p_{R}>R_{T}, p_{G}>G_{T}, p_{B}>B_{T}$}
\newcommand{\CenterColumnA}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestColumnA}][c]{#1}}
\newcommand{\CenterColumnB}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestColumnB}][c]{#1}}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
p \quad\CenterColumnA{fuego}    &\CenterColumnB{\WidestColumnB} \\
p \quad\CenterColumnA{no-fuego} &\CenterColumnB{resto}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```