# Smaller \lbrace than expected

Tags: equations, braces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format this equation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39728/how-do-i-format-this-equation-in-latex)

```
\begin{equation}
p_{GL}=
\lbrace
\begin{array}{@{} l c @{}}
0.59p_R+0.3p_G+0.11p_B & \text{p es un pixel del fuego}    \\
0 & \text{p no es pixel del fuego}
\end{array}
\label{eq4}
\end{equation}
```

That's the code of an equation but the `\lbrace` doesn't cover the two lines of equations.

Comment: `\left\lbrace` before the array, and `\right.` after it. That's how I've written in the previous answer to a question of yours. Please, consider deleting this question. Inside `\text`, write `$p$`, not simply `p`, as it's a math variable.

Comment: The linked document is the same

Comment: I'm in Japan, and post new year celebrations, the question @MarcoDaniel links to *still* badly hurts my brain. I had to alter the title. Perhaps it's just new year cheer that powers me, but I'm going to mark this one down.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I voted to close ;) and I am in 2011 ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I voted to close, from the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  p_{GL}=\left\{
    \begin{array}{@{} l c @{}}
      0.59p_R+0.3p_G+0.11p_B & \text{$p$ es un pixel del fuego} \\
      0 & \text{$p$ no es pixel del fuego}
    \end{array}\right.
  \label{eq4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If the `p` contained within the descriptions (or conditions) on the right refers to the same `p` as in the equation, then use `$p$` instead similar things should be formatted similarly.

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) also provides the `cases` environment which using a *very* similar layout by default:

```
\begin{equation}
  p_{GL}=\begin{cases}
      0.59p_R+0.3p_G+0.11p_B & \text{p es un pixel del fuego} \\
      0 & \text{p no es pixel del fuego}
    \end{cases}
  \label{eq4}
\end{equation}
```

In essence, it also typesets an `array`, but with a `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}` column alignment. This adds a little more space between the two columns (`\quad`), and typesets both `l`eft-aligned.

Comment: @Werner: Why not use `{cases}` which is exactly for this kind of thing?

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeGoutet. I've added it, and mentioned the differences in alignment from what the OP used.

Answer (score 5):

this can also be done in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 p_{GL}=
 \begin{cases}
  0.59p_R+0.3p_G+0.11p_B & \text{$p$ es un pixel del fuego}    \\
  0 & \text{$p$ no es pixel del fuego}
 \end{cases}
\label{eq4}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but because I'm picky, could you please add an image of the output of this code?

Comment: @CounterTerrorist -- thanks.  there's no faq for how to do this; i've been looking for half an hour for directions, and the only ones i've found say post from a url, but i don't have access to an outgoing url (behind a rather well regulated firewall).  someday i'll figure it out.

Comment: Are you having trouble uploading an image that you have, or creating the image that you want to upload? Perhaps [How do you crop an attached pdf?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/how-do-you-crop-an-attached-pdf) is of interest.

Comment: @Werner -- the problem is in finding instructions for uploading the image.  i've just posted a question to the meta list asking that this information be put in the faq.